# Queue up a list of YouTube videos in succession

Tags: youtube

Sometimes I like to watch YouTube while doing something else, like washing up or doing exercise.

Is there an easy way to queue up a string of YouTube videos and have them play one after the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every thumbnail in YouTube has a plus sign in the top bottom corner that appears when you mouse over it. Clicking it will add the video to a queue visible at the bottom of the screen.

[image: YouTube add to queue]

Comment: As of January 2014, [I only see the 'Watch later' button,](http://i.imgur.com/hg7JzkX.png) no plus sign.

Answer (score 1):

My [open-source web-based project named Streamly](https://github.com/LNFWebsite/Streamly) does this very thing by allowing you to drag and drop videos to make a queue.

[image: Streamly]

Full disclosure: I created Streamly in my free time and do not accept any donations. Streamly is MIT licensed.

Answer (score 0):

The website [queuemusic.org](http://queuemusic.org/) lets you to set up a playlist of YouTube videos.

Comment: This domain no longer resolves

Comment: yeah, I guess ytbe playlists got them offline

Answer (score 0):

In YouTube Help there's a page named [Queue videos on your computer](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9546304?hl=en) explaining how to add videos to your queue. You have at least the following two options

1. Click More [image] near the video and select add to queue
2. Hover over the video and select Add to queue [image].